# saving the individual results and masks in a batch process

Tags: imagej

When I run a batch process using a macro in Imagej FIJI it does not save the result table separately for each image, named after the image, an it overwrites the mask (processed image) with the same (first) mask (image).

I can filter the results table after but it would be nice to have separate results files named after each image, and I want to save each processed image (mask) for reviewed. I would like to rewrite the code and bypass using the process-batch tool, but am not experienced.  Am also willing to use the batch processing tool if I can save things in the right manner.  Advice and guidance welcome.  One iteration of the example code provided below.

```
run("Set Scale...", "distance=471 known=1000 unit=micron");
File.openSequence("C:/Users/jmitchell/Desktop/imagej test/");
run("Median...", "radius=2");
run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50");
run("Bandpass Filter...", "filter_large=40 filter_small=3 suppress=None tolerance=5 autoscale saturate");
run("8-bit");
setAutoThreshold("Default dark");
//run("Threshold...");
setOption("BlackBackground", true);
run("Convert to Mask", "method=Intermodes background=Dark calculate black");
run("Set Measurements...", "area bounding feret's display redirect=None decimal=1");
run("Fill Holes", "slice");
run("Analyze Particles...", "size=5-5000 show=Masks exclude add slice");
selectWindow("Mask of imagej test");
roiManager("Measure");
saveAs("Results", "C:/Users/jim/Desktop/imagej test/Results/Results.csv");
selectWindow("imagej test");
close();
```